# How to permanently and irrevocably block websites on Firefox?

Tags: internet, block

With Internet Explorer it's simple: you go to the settings menu, add websites you want to block, just randomly enter a sequence of letters and numbers so you cannot ever know the password, and it's done. (You could uninstall and re-install Explorer, but that's too big a pain to actually do that.)

With Firefox, its a different question. The main method is to add certain add-ons, like blocksite. However, add-ons like this have one FATAL flaw: you just deactivate the add-on and restart Firefox (which in all takes just a few seconds), et voilá... Too easy a by-pass to block you from not visiting certain websites.

I need to work on my bloody thesis, and seriously need to block like 10 websites. HOW?! Please help.

PS: can't have anything to do with the router, since there are several people using it, and adding URLs in the HOST also ain't good enough...

Comment: Jeez, exercise some self control already.

Comment: Wait...are you saying you need to work on a thesis paper, and you just want to keep yourself from going to a certain set of web sites while doing it?

Comment: Please tell me I'm misinterpreting the question's intent.

Comment: If you can't concentrate on your thesis, you probably don't deserve whatever degree you are about to complete.

Comment: My advice - ritalin or adderal- ADHD can be treated by a professional

Comment: Unplug. Your. Network. Cable.

Comment: Thanks, very helpfull! In fact, superhelpfull! Great website, with kind and helpfull people!

Comment: @Jan thanks for reading the FAQ before posting. You know, the one that says that this site is for professional systems administrators that manage computers/servers in a professional setting. Your question is **obviously** both relevant and wanted here.

Answer (score 4):

Install a proxy server that blocks requests from your machine to the websites. If I'm really reading that you're addicting to a series of sites to the point where it interferes with your work or life, you might want to consider therapy as well. Seriously. If it's interfering with your life, you need to seek assistance.

There is such a thing as Internet Addiction...

Comment: Not addicted it's just too easy a coffe break that always runs out, the internet is jus very interesting and there are too many links. Good enough for you?

Comment: Very defensive, considering my advice. You're unable to keep yourself without PERMANENTLY BLOCKING websites from getting your work done, and then you insult me for telling you that you might need to seek assistance. Hmm...

Comment: The college I went to had a professor that did work on Internet Addiction. I know it's real. Your question was basically pleading with people to tell you how to permanently keep you disconnected so you could get your THESIS written. That tells me you *have a problem*.

Comment: So either take your defensive attitude and shove it, or really...reread your question and what you're asking and ask yourself what that question is really saying. To me, and several others that looked, it shows someone who really has a problem and should be getting help.

Comment: Is that "good enough for you?"

Comment: +1 Like a moderate case of Internet Addiction.

Comment: "Not addicted it's just too easy a..." Okay, whatever you say. "I'm not an alcoholic, I just need you to take these bottles and put them in a locked cabinet and hide the key where I can't find them because it's too easy to have a little bit and I need to get my work done..." *Get Help.*

Answer (score 2):

Given the apparent lack of self-control, register for OpenDNS.org and configure your machine to use their nameservers.  Then blacklist the sites you can't keep yourself away from.  Added bonus: works for everything.  No need to jack around with reinstalling IE.

[other commentary reserved for future use]